# Angularjs attribute literal value vs. expression evaluation

Tags: html, angularjs, attributes

I'm having some trouble to understand how angularjs decides how to evaluate attributes. For exemple, using `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"></div>
```

the `item in items` part will be evaluated as an expression, looking for the content of `items` array set somewhere in the controller.

But using `ng-src`:

```
<img ng-src="/path/to/img/"></img>
```

the `path/to/img/` will be considered a literal. If I want to make it 'dynamic' I must write:

```
<img ng-src="/path/to/img/{{id}}"></img>
```

where `id` is set in the controller.

Question: how do I choose which behaviour to follow when defining custom attributes for my custom directive?

Comment: reading the docs helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to choose from. Expressions in attribute values are interpolated by [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) service. And the latter uses [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service to evaluate each expression in string.

Some directives (`ng-if`, `ng-hide`) expect nothing but expression in attribute, which is usually designated in API documentation. In this case the brackets can be omitted, and the expression will be evaluated within directive - [`$scope.$watch` is being used often](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L89) instead of calling `$interpolate` explicitly.

`ng-repeat` attribute syntax (it is referred as ['repeat expression'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#usage) in documentation) is parsed by [the directive itself](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L339) and isn't related to Angular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Defining your attributes as expressions will give you huge possibility in directives chain - you will escape isolate scope error that made us all straggle. A specially chains with ng-repeat or another default ones.

What I saw in bootstrap code and started to use - I $eval expressions within own scope then passed to directives local variables instead of defining in isolate scope.

```
<div custom some-val='ctrl.data'></div>

//directive link or controller
var private = $scope.$eval($attrs.someVar);
```

Only con for $eval is that it's good for static variables. For dynamic you need either already evaluated value or best way is to put it into ng-model that can be shared between directives (fix me if I'm wrong)

Or just run watcher on result of expression that is much simpler.

Comment: You are free to check any of templates in bootstrap templates js. If ppl use that so often and they are using such approach without side effects, probably that's a good splution.